# Save image from browserfield blackberry

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

```
BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
    protocolController = new ProtocolController(browserField)
    {
        public void handleNavigationRequest(final BrowserFieldRequest request) throws Exception
        {
            try
            {
                //save image from <a href="clickimage"><img src="http://mydomain.com/image.jpg></a>
            }
            catch (Throwable e)
            {

            }
        }
        public InputConnection handleResourceRequest(BrowserFieldRequest request) throws Exception {
            return super.handleResourceRequest(request);
        }
    };
    myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.CONTROLLER, protocolController);
    myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
    myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.CONNECTION_FACTORY, _factory);



    browserField = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);

    URLlink = "http://mydomain.com";

    browserField.requestContent(URLlink);
```

I use browserfield for my blackberry application that open web application from server. I try to save image from the web triggered by a href link from web page to SDCard/blackberry storage. how to do this?
Addition information: when i add BrowserFieldConfig.CONTROLLER, my web application cannot be opened. if i remove it, it works well...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you review the BrowserField information that you will find on the official BlackBerry developer site

[Creating a field to display web content](http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/documentation/html_content_1970202_11.html)

and also some tutorial information including:

[BrowserField-Sample-Code-Create-your-first-BrowserField](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BrowserField-Sample-Code-Create-your-first-BrowserField2/ta-p/495508)

[BrowserField-Sample-Code-Using-the-BrowserFieldConfig-class](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BrowserField-Sample-Code-Using-the-BrowserFieldConfig-class/ta-p/495716)

[BrowserField-Sample-Code-Using-the-BrowserFieldListener-class](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BrowserField-Sample-Code-Using-the-BrowserFieldListener-class/ta-p/496213)

Now I do not understand what you are trying to do specifically.  I am not sure how you want to trigger this capture or how you are expecting to retain the bytes from the image.

But I suspect that this article will help:

[How-to-Implement-a-Web-Cache-for-Your-BrowserField2-Application](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-Implement-a-Web-Cache-for-Your-BrowserField2-Application/ta-p/817911)

This article explains how you can capture and save downloaded bytes, in this case to save you downloading them again.  In your case you will have a different reason but still want to save the bytes.

Please review all of this information and refine your application.  If you continue to have problems, please explain how you are attempting to initiate the capture and what problems you are having with your approach in detail.  Your current question is not detailed enough, it does not demonstrate knowledge or the methods you have tried.  I also suggest asking one question at a time.